# SQL: How to order bulk data in trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a simple trigger that runs when a user inserts rows in a table.

Since there can also be bulk inserts and the insert order matters, is there a way to preserve it within the trigger ?

Could it be done like this or is there a better way to do it ?

```
ALTER TRIGGER simpleTrigger
ON shop
AFTER INSERT AS

SELECT * INTO #orderedInserted from inserted i ORDER BY i.Emp_Sal

declare @empid int;
    declare @empname varchar(100);
    declare @empsal decimal(10,2);
    declare @audit_action varchar(100);

    select @empid=#orderedInserted.Emp_ID from inserted i;  
    select @empname=#orderedInserted.Emp_Name from inserted i;  
    select @empsal=#orderedInserted.Emp_Sal from inserted i;    
    set @audit_action='Inserted Record -- After Insert Trigger.';

    insert into Employee_Test_Audit
           (Emp_ID,Emp_Name,Emp_Sal,Audit_Action,Audit_Timestamp) 
    values(@empid,@empname,@empsal,@audit_action,getdate());
GO;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like this

```
ALTER TRIGGER simpleTrigger
ON shop
AFTER INSERT AS

    insert into Employee_Test_Audit
           (Emp_ID,Emp_Name,Emp_Sal,Audit_Action,Audit_Timestamp) 
    select i.Emp_ID, i.Emp_Name, i.Emp_Sal, 'Inserted Record -- After Insert Trigger.', getdate()
    from inserted i
    order by i.Emp_Sal

GO;
```

but if you do not have identity column in `Employee_Test_Audit`, ORDER BY does not matter

Answer (score 1):

Very simple, you don't use variables :

```
ALTER TRIGGER simpleTrigger
ON shop
AFTER INSERT AS    
    declare @audit_action varchar(100);
    set @audit_action='Inserted Record -- After Insert Trigger.';

    insert into Employee_Test_Audit
           (Emp_ID,Emp_Name,Emp_Sal,Audit_Action,Audit_Timestamp) 
    SELECT i.Emp_ID, i.Emp_Name, i.Emp_sal, @audit_action, getdate() from inserted i ORDER BY i.Emp_Sal ;
GO;
```